# Как создать мобильное меню с дабл тапом или аналогичной логикой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет

Не могу придумать, как сделать данное меню

И так, обычная мобильная навигация, начинается при <1024

Структура:

```html
 <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="js-open-sub-menu"></a>
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li>
            <a class="js-one-more-sub" href="#"></a>
            <ul class="subbest-list-ever">
              <li>
                <a href=""></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Максимальный уровень вложенности - 2 уровня.

Все бы хорошо, но у меня есть разводящие страницы. То есть, не можем дать `e.preventDefault()` для `.js-one-more-sub` и `.js-open-sub-menu`. При первом тапе(клике) должен открываться саб-лист, при втором клике - переходить на страницу

Спасибо

Comment: А на счет мобильной навигации. Но, но ведь есть экраны ноутбуков, которые меньше чем iPad (например MacBook Air 11).

Comment: @EugenEray И как это сделать? Как я могу определить второй клик по тому же пункту?

Comment: Сейчас, сек, я сверстаю и покажу.

Comment: @EugenEray Был бы очень благодарен. До сих пор не придумал работающего варианта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так: по клику (в вашем случае заменить событие на тап) проверять есть ли класс `open`; если его нет, то запрещаем стандартное поведение, т. е. переход по ссылке; после добавляем класс `open`. Как следствие, следующий клик (тап) уже будет обрабатываться как обычное нажатие на ссылку.

```js
let submenuLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.open-sub'));

submenuLinks.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('open')) e.preventDefault();

    e.target.classList.add('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-list,
.subbest-list-ever {
  display: none;
}

.open-sub.open+ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="open-sub js-open-sub-menu">Ссылка с сабменю</a>
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li>
        <a class="open-sub js-one-more-sub" href="http://yandex.ru">Ссылка с сабменю</a>
        <ul class="subbest-list-ever">
          <li>
            <a href="http://bing.com">Просто пункт меню</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Версия с jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.open-sub').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('open')) e.preventDefault();

    $(e.target).addClass('open');
  })
});
```

```css
.sub-list,
.subbest-list-ever {
  display: none;
}

.open-sub.open+ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="open-sub js-open-sub-menu">Ссылка с сабменю</a>
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li>
        <a class="open-sub js-one-more-sub" href="http://yandex.ru">Ссылка с сабменю</a>
        <ul class="subbest-list-ever">
          <li>
            <a href="http://bing.com">Просто пункт меню</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1й вариант дропает еррор

2й вариант отличный, спасибо большое Вам ! :)

Comment: Подправил первый вариант. Пожалуйста )